# How to create responsive iFrame Youtube embed without CSS

Tags: iframe, youtube

I'm trying to embed a YouTube video on a website called bucket.io, and I'm running into a problem with the video not formatting correctly on mobile.

I don't have access to any CSS customization, and every solution I've found for creating a responsive YouTube embed involves adding in a few lines.

Is there any way to fix this with the iFrame alone?

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't seem so, no. Embedded YouTube videos seem to require a static size and will do their own thing otherwise.

You'll need to use JavaScript. This seems to be a common enough issue that Chris Coyier made a jQuery plugin for this exact purpose: http://fitvidsjs.com/

For the record, a full list of every tag's attributes can be found on the W3 docs: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp